# Bubble Sort throws exception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm writing a program for class to show the ability to code the bubble sort.  I have been working on it for days, and can't seem to get it.  At least now it compiles, but throws an exception.
I commented the part that I am having problems with, the actual swapping of the elements in the array.

The program is supposed to generate an array of 20 randoms integers, and then sort them using the bubble sort, printing out each pass as it goes until it is complete.

```
import java.util.*;


public class BubbleSorting {


public static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
  int n = arr.size();
  int temp = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

   //this is the chunk of code that I am having problems with
     for (int j = i; j < (n-1); j++) {
        if (arr.get(n-1) < arr.get(j))
           temp = arr.get(j-1);
           arr.set(j-1, arr.get(j));
           arr.set(j, temp);
     }

   }
 }

private static void printOut(int pass, ArrayList<Integer> array) {
  System.out.print("Pass " + pass + ": ");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
     System.out.print(array.get(i) + ", ");
  }

  System.out.print(array.get(array.size() - 1) + "."); 
  System.out.println();


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
  String userInput = ""; 
  boolean endLoop = false;

  do{
     try{

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
           int element = (int)(1000.0 * Math.random());
           array.add(element);
        }
        System.out.print("\nUnsorted Array: ");

                //Displays the unsorted ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
           System.out.print(array.get(i) + ", ");
        }

        System.out.print(array.get(array.size() - 1) + "."); 
        System.out.println();
        bubbleSort(array);
     }
     catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("\nThere is an out of bounds error in the ArrayList.");
     }



     System.out.print("\nEnter Y to continue or N to quit: ");
        userInput = sc.nextLine();

     if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        endLoop = false;

     }
     else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        endLoop = true;
     }

     else { 
        System.out.println("\nYou did not enter Y or N.");
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
     }

    }while(endLoop == false);


   }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger? Or following your code by hand? For instance, what happens when you need to swap entries when `i = j = 0`?

Comment: When i = 0, and j = 0, you get index = -1 that's index out of bounds. Because your **j** starts from **i**.

Comment: It throws an exception but I'm not going to bother telling you what it is...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < (list.size() -i); j++) {
                if(list.get(j - 1) > list.get(j)) {
                    int temp = list.get(j-1);
                    list.set(j-1, list.get(j));
                    list.set(j, temp);
                }                   
            }
        }       
    }
```

You did 2 mistakes...first in the 1st for loop its `for(int j = 1; j < (list.size() -i); j++)` while you wrote `int j=i` and second is you did not cover the {} brackets in if loop condition.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Boy you missed the bracket inside the if statement.

```
//this is the chunk of code that I am having problems with
                for (int j = i; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                    if (arr.get(n - 1) < arr.get(j)) {//<------here this one
                        temp = arr.get(j - 1);
                        arr.set(j - 1, arr.get(j));
                        arr.set(j, temp);
                    }//<----this too
                }
```

---

only the first statement after the if is considered if you don't put the bracket.

Comment: Still it will not sort...this will only avoid the indexoutofbondsexception but will not sort..in the for loop its int j=1 not j=i...

Answer (score 0):

You might have a misunderstanding of how bubble sort works. Here is an example of how bubble sort works (taken from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

```
Let us take the array of numbers "5 1 4 2 8", and sort the array from lowest
number to greatest number using bubble sort. In each step, elements written
in bold are being compared. Three passes will be required.

First Pass
( 5 1 4 2 8 ) ( 1 5 4 2 8 ), Here, algorithm 
compares the first two elements, and swaps since 5 > 1.
( 1 5 4 2 8 ) ( 1 4 5 2 8 ), Swap since 5 > 4
( 1 4 5 2 8 ) ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Swap since 5 > 2
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Now, since these elements are already in order
(8 > 5), algorithm does not swap them.

Second Pass
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) ( 1 4 2 5 8 )
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Swap since 4 > 2
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
Now, the array is already sorted, but the algorithm does not know if it is
completed. The algorithm needs one whole pass without any swap to know it is
sorted.

Third Pass
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) ( 1 2 4 5 8 )
```

Now, compare that line of thinking to your code here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

   //this is the chunk of code that I am having problems with
     for (int j = i; j < (n-1); j++) {
        if (arr.get(n-1) < arr.get(j))
           temp = arr.get(j-1);
           arr.set(j-1, arr.get(j));
           arr.set(j, temp);
     }

}
```

Now, if you use the array in the example (5 1 4 2 8) and plug that into your code, it's going to end up comparing 8 to every given number, and since 8 is already the biggest, the if statement will always be false; no sorting will occur. Instead, compare two adjacent indexes at a time and use a boolean to indicate whether a swap occurred. Given this sort of functionality, the sort will continue swapping the biggest number as far as to the end of the array as possible. So, once there was no swap, you know the array has been sorted.  Therefore, you want the inner loop only going up to the already sorted portion, no further. If you compare sorted values, the sorting will end early. Try using this way of thinking and apply it to your code.